# Audit (taking over) existing SSISBD and review usage

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-server-2016

I am taking over the administration of a MSSQL 2016 Database Server, something that was dependant upon an ex employee, There's 10 databases approx 60gb and SSISDB at 400gb, report below.
I have no idea of what this is being used for, so am hesitant to delete or purge any data just yet without any true knowledge of it. My question is, is there a way to trace what is writing data to it?  I believe there is multiple versions of integration, some of which may not be valid, through KwS

```
Table Name #Records
internal.event_messages 267,452,338  
internal.operation_messages 267,452,340  
internal.event_message_context 251,162,315  
internal.execution_parameter_values 121,527,475  
internal.executable_statistics 19,520,041  
internal.operations 1,714,882
```

Comment: Stop asking strangers in the internet. But DO starting asking questions of the people in your own organization and perhaps the clients. Search for documentation of any type. Ask the users. First thing I personally would focus on is the disaster recovery plans and how they are currently implemented (if at all). In fact, I would make full backups of every existing database first to guarantee that you have a complete set. What you should not do is start "optimizing" things by looking for "unused" databases and tables.

Comment: SSISDB is a standard name for SQL Server Integration Services (SSIS). SSIS comes with a job to purge not needed data from the SSISDB.

Comment: There might be some issues with SSIDB settings, it seems quite a large one. If SSIS retention period setting has been left to 365 days, then you might want to pull it back to something like 50 days. Do not set it straight to 50 do it gradually (first set it to 330 then 310 and so on. wait for SSIS maintenance job to run between the changes)., SSIS has issues when it tries to clear a lot of data from SSISDB, sometimes it needs manual help: https://www.timmitchell.net/post/2018/12/30/clean-up-the-ssis-catalog/